# Data update in big data system

Tags: hive, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark Streaming and Hive. I want to insert or update data into exist table in hive using SparkSQL. But, I don't know check whether data existed. Please suggest me this question!

Comment: Hadoop echo system does not allow update...

Comment: Take a look at `HBase`